# Goolge GCP gsutil commands counterpart for gcloud ones

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Some google cloud shell commands related to `gsutil` (cloud storage) have counterpart for `gcloud` ones e.g.

```
gsutil mb gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

goes to

```
cloud storage buckets create gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Is this valid for all the existing gsutil commands?

Answer (score 1):

Is this valid for all the existing gsutil commands?

> Yes.[`gcloud storage`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) is a new set of Cloud Storage commands in Cloud SDK that has been innovated in order to be fast by default especially when it comes to data transfer rates and is created as an improvement to gsutil.

gcloud storage requires a lot less tweaking than gsutil to get good performance.All operations are performed in parallel by default as there are no major platform compatibility issues as there was with gsutil.Parallel composite uploads are enabled by default (with a warning)

[Should you use gsutil?](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil#should-you-use)

> Generally, you should use gcloud storage commands instead of gsutil commands:
>
> - The gsutil tool is a legacy Cloud Storage CLI and minimally maintained.
> - The gsutil tool does not support working with newer Cloud Storage features.
> - gcloud storage commands require less manual optimization in order to achieve the fastest upload and download rates.

And stated in [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#:%7E:text=gsutil%20is%20not%20the%20recommended%20CLI%20for%20Cloud%20Storage.%20Use%20gcloud%20storage%20commands%20in%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20CLI%20instead)

> gsutil is not the recommended CLI for Cloud Storage. Use gcloud storage commands in the Google Cloud CLI instead.

You can check more about the features of gcloud storage in this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-enables-super-fast-data-transfers) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-cli-for-your-data-transfers). And also have look at [link1](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/gsutils-vs-gcloud-storage-performance/m-p/598434) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145462/what-is-the-difference-between-gcloud-and-gsutil) for more information.