# Transfer files from one bucket to another in GCS with extension filteration

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to transfer a file from one bucket to another in GCS and for that I found this code (from [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#client-libraries) link):

```
import com.google.protobuf.Duration;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.StorageTransferServiceClient;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferProto.CreateTransferJobRequest;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.GcsData;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.ObjectConditions;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.Schedule;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.TransferJob;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.TransferJob.Status;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.TransferOptions;
import com.google.storagetransfer.v1.proto.TransferTypes.TransferSpec;
import com.google.type.Date;
import com.google.type.TimeOfDay;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TransferToNearline {
  /**
   * Creates a one-off transfer job that transfers objects in a standard GCS bucket that are more
   * than 30 days old to a Nearline GCS bucket.
   */
  public static void transferToNearline(
      String projectId,
      String jobDescription,
      String gcsSourceBucket,
      String gcsNearlineSinkBucket,
      long startDateTime)
      throws IOException {

    // Your Google Cloud Project ID
    // String projectId = "your-project-id";

    // A short description of this job
    // String jobDescription = "Sample transfer job of old objects to a Nearline GCS bucket.";

    // The name of the source GCS bucket to transfer data from
    // String gcsSourceBucket = "your-gcs-source-bucket";

    // The name of the Nearline GCS bucket to transfer old objects to
    // String gcsSinkBucket = "your-nearline-gcs-bucket";

    // What day and time in UTC to start the transfer, expressed as an epoch date timestamp.
    // If this is in the past relative to when the job is created, it will run the next day.
    // long startDateTime =
    //     new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2000-01-01 00:00:00").getTime();

    // Parse epoch timestamp into the model classes
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.setTimeInMillis(startDateTime);
    // Note that this is a Date from the model class package, not a java.util.Date
    Date date =
        Date.newBuilder()
            .setYear(startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))
            .setMonth(startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
            .setDay(startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .build();
    TimeOfDay time =
        TimeOfDay.newBuilder()
            .setHours(startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
            .setMinutes(startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
            .setSeconds(startCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND))
            .build();

    TransferJob transferJob =
        TransferJob.newBuilder()
            .setDescription(jobDescription)
            .setProjectId(projectId)
            .setTransferSpec(
                TransferSpec.newBuilder()
                    .setGcsDataSource(GcsData.newBuilder().setBucketName(gcsSourceBucket))
                    .setGcsDataSink(GcsData.newBuilder().setBucketName(gcsNearlineSinkBucket))
                    .setObjectConditions(
                        ObjectConditions.newBuilder()
                            .setMinTimeElapsedSinceLastModification(
                                Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(2592000 /* 30 days */)))
                    .setTransferOptions(
                        TransferOptions.newBuilder().setDeleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer(true)))
            .setSchedule(Schedule.newBuilder().setScheduleStartDate(date).setStartTimeOfDay(time))
            .setStatus(Status.ENABLED)
            .build();

    // Create a Transfer Service client
    StorageTransferServiceClient storageTransfer = StorageTransferServiceClient.create();

    // Create the transfer job
    TransferJob response =
        storageTransfer.createTransferJob(
            CreateTransferJobRequest.newBuilder().setTransferJob(transferJob).build());

    System.out.println("Created transfer job from standard bucket to Nearline bucket:");
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
}
```

This code is transferring files older than 30 days, as you can see the condition in ObjectConditions. But I want to filter the files on extension basis, for example I want only those files to be transferred which are let's say ".txt" or ".pdf" or anything, maybe ".mp3". I am not able to find it anywhere, can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the  Storage Transfer Service only able to filter by prefix, it does not support filter with suffixes

You can also use the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) command line tool to move files with the file extension

If you still want to continue with a storage transfer service to transfer from one bucket to another using suffix filtering, you may consider raising a [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) by describing your request in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read on gsutils page then one should ideally be using gcloud tools instead of gsutils. what is your say on this:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/discover-object-storage-gcloud

Why to use gsutils over gcloud tools?

Comment: @Thor my bad ,you should use gcloud storage commands instead of gsutil commands.I fixed the link. you can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77993821/18265638) why you should use gcloud storage commands.